# Visual Studio Code disabling Normal, Edit and Visual Mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my Visual Studio Code, I need to hit <kbd>I</kbd> to enter to the *edit mode*. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> for the *normal mode*. Selecting the word enables the *visual mode*.

In visual mode, I can't delete the line or word using the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. Are there any settings where I can disable these modes, so that I can directly go and start typing like a normal code editor?

Answer (score 71):

This is because the Vim extension is installed.

Go to *Extensions*, type Vim, and disable/uninstall.

Comment: Great thanks! Nice catch.

Comment: this is the most accurate resolution

Comment: you just saved my whole existence, literally

Comment: FInally.. oh god... such an annoying feature.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Visual Studio Code with [Unity 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) because of the fact it's lighter on resources and better than [MonoDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) and have added the *unity3d-pack* (which force installs [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) for some unknown reason and you can't disable the Vim extension), you can override its startup mode in your personal *settings.json* file by adding

`"vim.startInInsertMode": true`

to it. I personally hate the way it is set up as well, but the extensions I use with Unity 3D outweigh the downfalls of the other ones.