# Cursor bug in VSCode, deletes last character

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I restarted my computer, VSCode started to behave oddly. When I open any file:

1. The cursor's style seems to be "block", although in the settings it's "line".
2. If I type any character, the character doesn't get written into the file - VSCode actually deletes the character located where the cursor is
3. After that, I can finally write new characters and the cursor returns back to normal (a line)

Here's how it looks:

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

Does anyone know if this is bug on their end? I'm using VSCode@1.45.1.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it seems that this was caused by the [Vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension I recently installed. There's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819388/visual-studio-code-disabling-normal-edit-and-visual-mode) opened about it.