# I can't use CTRL + C to copy code from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot use the CTRL + C to copy and the CTRL + X to cut code using Visual Studio Code. Whenever I try to copy some part of my code the Visual Studio Code changes from "--INSERT--" to "--NORMAL--".

Comment: Have a look if you have overwritten the default keystroke.

Comment: I don't use VS Code, but `-- INSERT --` looks like some sort of `vim` mode, which uses its own clipboard system. I am unsure about how VSCode integrates it, but you can refer to [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste) for regular vim.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Sadly I haven't

Comment: @HeySora I guess I need to finally learn vim

Comment: @ano7 No! You can disable it using [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44487597/6401290)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable VIM extension into the VS Code.