# VScode macos - Jupyter Notebook Cells states and shortcuts

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on VScode 1.77 for macos with a jupyter-notebook file, in a trusted workspace, however when I open it I can't edit the cell right away. I see in the left bottom that cells are in --NORMAL-- mode and when I can edit them in --INSERT-- mode.

On the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks): *"While working with code cells, a cell can be in three states: unselected, command mode, and edit mode"*. Is --NORMAL-- mode the same as command mode? Why they are in this status when I open a file.ipynb?

Again from the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) *"To move from command mode to edit mode, press the Enter key"*. Enter key however seems not working for me, instead trying empirically I see

- a , i, s, o : allow me to activate insert mode
- q : recording
- k : cell up
- j : cell down
- w : moves the cursor from word to word
- Enter : just takes the cursor to the beginning of the cell

Why pressing the Enter key doesn't work for me and I have those other shortcuts? How do I go out from edit mode returning to command mode?

Also *"When in command or edit mode, use Comand+Enter to run the current cell or Shift+Enter to run the current cell and advance to the next"*. To me both Ctrl+Enter and Shift+Enter just run the current cell, while command+enter just create another line inside the cell both for edit mode and command mode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figure it out. Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819388/visual-studio-code-disabling-normal-edit-and-visual-mode), I tried to unistall Vim extensions and everything seems to work normally.

In particular I think NORMAL, VISUAL and INSERT are all form of edit mode, to get command mode I had to press esc+esc (now without the vim extension just one esc is enough like in jupyter notebook with anaconda).

All my shortcuts now are in line with the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).